# C++ scanf error (Access violation while saving)

Tags: c, scanf

i have a problem with this few lines of code. It works fine in any other compiler than Visual Studio.

```
int i = 0; 
    char* func[20];
    char com[15];
    while (true)
    {
        scanf_s("%s", com);
        //printf("%s\n", com);
        if (com == "ACTUAL\0")
            cout << "TE\n";
        i++;
    }
```

I try to scan a word to char variable ( i have to use chars, cant use string in this exercise ). Im getting this error: (in english it means :Access violation while saving to location )

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltb5v.png]

But everything works fine in other compilers. I get mad because i'm looking at posts about scan strings into char and it looks very similar to my code.
(Sorry if i should tag C instead C++)

Comment: FYI: `if (com == "ACTUAL\0")` does not compare the strings. Please also do not post images of errors.

Comment: @ChrisMM i can see, and im working on it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `scanf_s` to read a `%s` format specifier, you also have to pass the length of the buffer. That's the key difference between `scanf` and `scanf_s`.

```
scanf_s("%s", com, (unsigned)_countof(com));
```

That's if you even want to use `scanf` family functions at all. I'd prefer `fgets` because it's simpler to read the input first then later parse it (with `sscanf` or similar)

Comment: Oh, Thaks a lot. It works fine now. I will look at fgets. Does it read string to variable? (like scanf "%s")?

Comment: @Kawson https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694042/1773434

Comment: @Kawson - Govind Parmer is correct.   You *MUST* specify buffer size as your final argument.  Example (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf): `int n = sscanf_s(input, "%d%f%s", &i, &x, str1, (rsize_t)sizeof str1);`.  ALSO: you CANNOT use "==" to compare strings.  Use [strcmp()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) instead.  FINALLY: you should *ALWAYS* check the return value from scanf/scanf_s.